# Resizing 280m print in Adobe Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, image-quality, dpi

So basically my client wants to make a custom whooping 280m print that i think is being used for the floor. I dont know how this works (if its with a sticker or something) but its basically a walkable monopoly board. I made it on photoshop as 280 m x 280 m with 200 dpi is this right?

Comment: m or cm? If it is m I have no clue if you can make something usable.

Comment: Photoshop ihas a maximum size of 300,000 pixels per side. You are proposing 2,2million pixels  That is 48 times the amount of pixels that photoshop can handle. It is safe to say that Photoshop is not the tool of choice for this job.

Comment: At 280x280 *meters*, I'm pretty sure this will not be printed and then applied as stickers to any floor. You and your client should be discussing this project with a flooring company.

Comment: At a size of 2x3 soccer pitches side by side, this floor plan would be visible from space. Forget flooring company, bring in some heavy landscaping equipment.

Comment: Assuming a regular Monopoly board, that would make each square about 28mx28m. That's more than 'walkable'. If you were standing in the middle of a square, you'd propbably not see more than just that single square.

Comment: I think we can summarize: someone involved in a project of this magnitude should not have to ask questions on an Internet Q&A site, period.

Answer (score 4):

280 m^2 is big, scratch that its enormous in size. It is not that its not possible to fill, it is. It is just that this is a very big task, your going to need quite the team to pull this off.

You are going to have some logistical problems on a quite big scale. This is no ordinary graphics design job, it is a engineering job. Get the manufacturers and contractors in loop now.

To understand the enormity of your task think of this:

- Normal office paper weighs at about 80 grams per square meter at 280 times 280 meters that paper would have a weight of 6.272 tons. And that is quite flimsy stuff. To haul that you need more than one trailer truck, in most locales for weight allowance alone.
- If you were to make it at 200 dpi it would be roughly 2.2 million pixels by 2.2 million pixels 4.48 * 10^14 pixels. Squared stuff grows quite fast in size and the raw image data in cmyk would eat 19.36 Terabytes of memory for one layer. Just saving this monster on disk would be a undertaking.

  So even if you were to design it in tiles it would still eat up several diskstations worth of diskspace. So clearly this is not feasible with standard tools.
- You would have to design in vector form, make details one at a time as tiles and keep talking to your vendors and client to pinpoint the budget. It is possible to do this if you sparingly use graphics and concentrate on the important stuff.

Comment: Just @joojaa putting things in perspective :)

Comment: @PieBie sure, this kind of job would probably net you a 5-6 number comission.

Answer (score 1):

How big is this thing supposed to be? Because what you describe isn't much larger than a sheet of paper. This sounds like the sort of thing you would be doing in vector anyway, If he is going to have it printed on vinyl then it must be done in vector format in illustrator or Corel draw. After you have done the art in vector the size makes no difference anyway.

Comment: Its 280 meters x 280 meters.